# Pycharm bug when linking turtle module with separate files

Tags: python, pycharm

The issue begins when I try to link my modules/files, the turtle class does not instantiate objects to their proper values. I tried changing paths for my python interpreter, but that didn't work. The funny thing is, though- the turtle class works fine with only **one** module, meaning the object from the class Turtle receives the correct data I give to instantiate it: shape, size, color, etc.

```
# player.py
from turtle import Turtle


class Player(Turtle):

    def __int__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('turtle')


screen.exitonclick()

#***********************
# main.py
from player import Player
from turtle import Screen

screen = Screen()
player = Player()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Please clarify why you believe that "the turtle class does not instantiate objects to their proper values". Please dump the values and show what you think is wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That is the issue; It's not very well explainable either- I'll try my best, though. Okay, so in my IDE, I have two files: main.py & player.py as seen above; when I try to set the shape of the player object in the constructor as 'turtle', which gives the instance the shape of a turtle, PyCharm does not pass that value to the object so it never 'becomes' a turtle. My previous projects have the same format, but the strange thing or the issue I'm trying to get it is that only the present and future projects I create- when separating files seem to cause a bug within PyCharm, since my other IDEs

Comment: Seem to work fine. I switched the interpreter back and forth to older/previous versions, and the problem was still present. It's a very strange bug since the code itself is not wrong; you can run the code above as two files (player, main), and it will work fine on your end, but for some reason, PyCharm is having issues working with the turtle library. It's difficult to explain since the issue is not visible in my code, but I believe it's internal. But like I previously stated, the code works fine if the code is only in one file/module, but if I were to separate the code, PyCharm acts strange.